# Sendex + MODX REVO рассылка смс

Tags: modx, revo, рассылка

Возник вопрос, как получить номера телефонов зарегистрированных пользователей, подписанных на определенную подписку. Сейчас используется следующий плагин для генерации рассылки:

```
<?php
/**
** Плагин, при публикации ресурса в указанном разделе, передает текст ресурса 
** в шаблон Sendex и отправляет подписку в очередь
**
** OnDocPublished срабатывает только при публикации ресурса через контекстное 
** меню документа в дереве ресурсов
**
** В шаблоне sendex в месте куда нужно вставлять контент должен быть 
** тег <div id="content"></div>
*/

if ($modx->event->name == 'OnDocPublished') {

if ($resource->get('parent') != 3) return; // 3 - ID раздела с новостями

// Получение шаблона

$response = $modx->runProcessor('element/template/get', array(
    'id' => 4 // 4 - ID шаблона sendex
));

if ($response->isError()) {
    $modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, 'SendexOnNewsPublished - ошибка чтения шаблона. '.$response->getMessage());
    return;
} else {
    $template = $response->getObject();
}
$newTplContent = preg_replace('/(<div.*?id="content"[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/div>)/i', '<div id="content">
<a href=http://site-name.com/index.php?id='.$resource->get('id').'>'.$resource->get('pagetitle').'</a>
</div>', $template['content'], 1);

$data = $template;
$data['content'] = $newTplContent;

//Запись контента новости в шаблон

$response = $modx->runProcessor('element/template/update', $data);

if ($response->isError()) {
    $modx->log(modX::LOG_LEVEL_ERROR, 'SendexOnNewsPublished - ошибка записи в шаблон. '.$response->getMessage());
    return;
} else {
    $modx->cacheManager->clearCache();
}

// Отправка шаблона в очередь рассылки

$modx->addPackage('sendex', MODX_CORE_PATH . 'components/sendex/model/');

if ($newsletter = $modx->getObject('sxNewsletter', $resource->getTVValue('poroda'))) { // $resource->getTVValue('poroda') - ID рассылки
    $response = $newsletter->addQueues();
    if ($response !== true) {
        echo $response;die;
    }
}

}
return;
```

надо вызвать вот это

```
 send("gate.iqsms.ru", 80, "api_login", "api_password", 
          "7хххххххххх", "text here", "iqsms", "wap.yousite.ru");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $sql ='SELECT phone FROM `modx_user_attributes` WHERE email IN (SELECT `email` FROM `modx_sendex_subscribers` WHERE `newsletter_id`= '.$resource->getTVValue("poroda").')';
    $q = $modx->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();
    $result = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($result as $res){
        echo $res['phone'];
    }
```